# Duplicate case error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, duplicates, case

```
public LabelsFactoryImpl() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * <!-- begin-user-doc -->
     * <!-- end-user-doc -->
     * @generated
     */
    @Override
    public EObject create(EClass eClass) {
        switch (eClass.getClassifierID()) {
            case LabelsPackage.AREA_LABEL: return createAreaLabel();
            case LabelsPackage.AREA_LABEL_VALUE: return createAreaLabelValue();
            case LabelsPackage.COMMON_BORDER_RELATIONSHIP_LABEL: return createCommonBorderRelationshipLabel();
            case LabelsPackage.COMMON_BORDER_RELATIONSHIP_LABEL_VALUE: return createCommonBorderRelationshipLabelValue();
            case LabelsPackage.POPULATION_LABEL: return createPopulationLabel();
            case LabelsPackage.POPULATION_LABEL_VALUE: return createPopulationLabelValue();
            case LabelsPackage.RELATIVE_PHYSICAL_RELATIONSHIP_LABEL: return createRelativePhysicalRelationshipLabel();
            case LabelsPackage.RELATIVE_PHYSICAL_RELATIONSHIP_LABEL_VALUE: return createRelativePhysicalRelationshipLabelValue();
            case LabelsPackage.TRANSPORT_RELATIONSHIP_LABEL: return createTransportRelationshipLabel();
            case LabelsPackage.TRANSPORT_RELATIONSHIP_LABEL_VALUE: return createTransportRelationshipLabelValue();
            case LabelsPackage.PHYSICAL_RELATIONSHIP_LABEL_VALUE: return createPhysicalRelationshipLabelValue();
            case LabelsPackage.ROAD_TRANSPORT_RELATIONSHIP_LABEL: return createRoadTransportRelationshipLabel();
            case LabelsPackage.ROAD_TRANSPORT_RELATIONSHIP_LABEL_VALUE: return createRoadTransportRelationshipLabelValue();
            case LabelsPackage.EARTH_SCIENCE_LABEL: return createEarthScienceLabel();
            case LabelsPackage.EARTH_SCIENCE_LABEL_VALUE: return createEarthScienceLabelValue();
            case LabelsPackage.PARENT_LABEL: return createParentLabel();
            case LabelsPackage.PARENT_LABEL_VALUE: return createParentLabelValue();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The class '" + eClass.getName() + "' is not a valid classifier"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        }
    }
```

I'm receiving a "Duplicate case error" in Eclipse for the above code. Eclipse underlines the "AREA_LABEL" line, "PARENT_LABEL" line, and "PARENT_LABEL_VALUE" line as duplicates even though they seem to be different. I assume this is a syntax error but I'm not sure. Let me know if you need any other code/classes. Thank you.

Comment: What are the values stored in those labels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all depends on the actual *values* of those labels, they might have different names but the same values. Check their definition, it's hard to tell their actual types and values from just the piece of code you posted.

To fix this error, make sure that each of the constants *really* has different values. Or use an enumeration, as suggested by @djjeck.

Comment: i.e. always use Java enums when possible

Comment: Check all cases. I just dealt with this using Eclipse Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0), Build id: 20200615-1200 which marks the first case in the switch block and any case which duplicates a preceding case but doesn't mark the first duplicate case occurrence (unless it happens to be the first case).